# Mapping column values onto each other in pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have two dataframes with labels.

The first is the datetime occurance of the labels.

The 2nd is the frequeny at which these labels occure.

**df_labels**

| DateTime | Labels |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/21 | 4 |
| 02/02/21 | 7 |
| 03/02/21 | 9 |
| 04/02/21 | 9 |
| 06/02/21 | 7 |
| 05/02/21 | 4 |

**df_label_frequency**

| Label | Label Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 40 |
| 7 | 66 |
| 9 | 12 |

These tabels are 10,000 + rows in reality FYI.
I want to add the Label Frequency row value to each row in the df_labels table like so:

| DateTime | Labels | Label Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/21 | 4 | 40 |
| 02/02/21 | 7 | 66 |
| 03/02/21 | 9 | 12 |
| 04/02/21 | 9 | 12 |
| 06/02/21 | 7 | 66 |
| 05/02/21 | 4 | 40 |

I have been scratching my head and staring at this problem for hours, I have tried lamba functions, merging, if statements, for loops and just can't figure it out. I know it will be so obvious but I just dont get it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this map with a dictionary and zipping df columns together:

```
df_labels["Label Frequency"] = df_labels["Labels"].map(
    dict(zip(df_label_frequency["Label"], df_label_frequency["Label Frequency"]))
)
df_labels
```

Output:

```
   DateTime  Labels  Label Frequency
0  01/01/21       4               40
1  02/02/21       7               66
2  03/02/21       9               12
3  04/02/21       9               12
4  06/02/21       7               66
5  05/02/21       4               40
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
df_labels['Label Frequency'] = df_labels['Labels'].map(df_label_frequency.set_index('Label')['Label Frequency'])
```

Comment: There is no need to add to_dict.  map will use a series.

Answer (score 1):

If your "Label" in the frequency table is an index just use "apply":

```
df_labels["Label Frequency"] = df_labels['Labels'].apply(lambda x: df_label_frequency[x]).values
```

I think it's index because you can get this table like

```
df_labels['Label'].value_counts()
```